# Getting data from MainActivity and handling it in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-volley, fragment-lifecycle

I have a problem while getting data from MainActivity and handle it on Fragment.

At first, there are 4 Fragments. I am using `TabLayout` and `ViewPager`. Whenever a fragment selected from the Tab, it triggers `onPageSelected()` method. Here, I instantiate transaction and send the string URL according to selected Fragment by the means of `setArguments()`. In the Fragment I receive string URL with the help of `getArguments()` successfully, however when I retrieve data from API using that URL, `fetchData()(using Volley)` method ignores it.

**Below is onPageSelected() method**

```
@Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
                                R.id.linear_frame,
                                FragmentAllLanguages.newInstance(0, NetworkUtils.URL_ALL_NEWS))
                                .commit();
                        break;
```

**onCreateView() of Fragment**

```
        if (getArguments() != null) {
        fetchData(getArguments().getString(ARGS_URL));
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "URL is " + getArguments().getString(ARGS_URL), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "IF IF IF" + getArguments().getInt(ARGS_ID));
    } else {
        fetchData(NetworkUtils.URL_ALL_NEWS);
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "else part", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e(TAG, "ELSE ELSE ELSE");
    }
```

**Finally, "interesting" log file when fragment selected**

```
04-18 02:43:20.764 5610-5610/com.example.orkhan.nexeber E/Volley: ELSE ELSE ELSE
04-18 02:43:20.768 5610-5610/com.example.orkhan.nexeber E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
04-18 02:43:20.770 5610-5683/com.example.orkhan.nexeber D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9e105420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9e103370)
04-18 02:43:20.794 5610-5610/com.example.orkhan.nexeber E/Volley: IF IF IF2
04-18 02:43:20.850 5610-5610/com.example.orkhan.nexeber E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

My question is why if statement called twice though it is chosen once in Tab?

My version is maybe because of `beginTransaction`'s delay, I mean, it cannot send data as fast as `oncreateView()` method's call. That's why at first **else** part is executed and then when **if** part is executed RecyclerView ignores it.

Comment: The Answer is on your Logs if you read it carefully.

It's probably because you didn't attach any `adapter` to your `RecyclerView`

Comment: @AliZeynali No, I already find an answer. Whenever it creates new instance it calls Fragment's onCreatView 2 times: once in newInstance class, the second when transaction happens.